# PayPal server integration does not pass data via the fetch body parameter

Tags: javascript, python, paypal

I'm following PayPal's server integration demo:
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

The following code does not appear to be passing data via the "body" parameter:

```
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('/paypal_api', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({name:"sammy"}),
            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(orderData) {
                return orderData.id;
            });
        },
```

I am, however, able to pass parameters within the URL. For example:

return fetch('/paypal_api/<some_variable>/', {

So I can get this working but am bugged that the POST method does not appear to be working as expected. Here's a snippet from my python server code:

class createOrder(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):

```
    print self.request.params
```

... and the print statement returns nothing (UnicodeMultiDict([])).

I'm 99% certain that I'm missing something obvious since google is not helping me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the request body as JSON

```py
import json

jsonstring = self.request.body
jsonobject = json.loads(jsonstring)
```